# Is there a simple way to merge the results of two json files in an angular app

Tags: json, angular

I am VERY new to angular so I'm trying to feel my way around.  We have a server that was designed to return JSON formatted data from a database to a C# client via a REST request.  On the server there are two different APIs, one for people and the other for addresses.  Each person has a unique ID that is contained in the address results for joining.  There is not an API that will return both in the same file because this was handled in the C# client.  I need to build an angular search screen that contains both the names and addresses in a single row.  Is there a simple way to merge the two JSON results together?

Editing to be clearer on my request.  I would like to merge the addresses with the person that they belong to so I can create a "person" class that contains their address (see below for my two classes and yes there can be multiple addresses per person).

```
export class AddressModel {
    constructor(
        public addressUID: string = '',
        public line1: string = '',
        public line2: string = '',
        public city: string = '',
        public state: string = '',
        public zipcode: string = '',
        public personUID: string = '',
    ) {}
}

export class PersonModel {
    constructor(
        public personUID: string = '',
        public firstName: string = '',
        public lastName: string = '',
        public addresses: AddressModel[] = new Array<AddressModel>(),
    ) {}
}
```

The goal is to be able to create a personArray that I can use to populate my webpage.

Answer (score 0):

```
const json1 = {...}
const json2 = {...}

const json_merged = {...json1, ...json2}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.